# Super simple JQuery issue has me stumped. Code will not fire off in <head> but will in <body>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have never seen this before. Something so simple I'm doing wrong.

My JQuery code just stopped working in the head tag, and now will only work in the body.

This will work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="foo">
  Click Me
</div>

<script type="application/javascript">
$('#foo').click(function(){
  alert("I got here");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this will not:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">
$('#foo').click(function(){
  alert("I got here");
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="foo">
  Click Me
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

A bit confused. I don't see the typo. Advice most appreciated!

Comment: simple solution ...use a ready handler. Can't run code on non existent elements.  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Yeah your body isn't ready without the DOMContentLoaded being fired off. Your page is being read like an english book. left to right top to bottom.

Comment: it worked in second case because the js code was after your `div#foo`

Comment: Just FYI you don't really need the `<script>` "type" attribute in an HTML5 page. Leaving it off works in all browsers, and keeping it in introduces the possibility of extremely irritating errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It happens because the DOM isn't yet loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').click(function(){
        alert("I got here");
    });
});
```

Or without using a specific library (I think it's more self-describing)

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function(){
        alert('I got here');
    };
};
```

HTML file is loaded sequentially, so your code works within the `body` because it fires after the `div` has been created, but it doesn't work within the `head` section because at that moment the `div` wasn't yet created. That's way is `.onload` event used - it guaranteed that nothing will be executed until the DOM isn't ready.

Comment: @edpotter: Well said.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your code runs *before* the element exists, so `$("#foo")` doesn't find it.

Unless you use the [`async` or `defer` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async), the code in your `script` tags is run *when it is encountered in the HTML*. So:

```
<script>/* your code here */</script>
<div id="foo">..</div>
```

...will not find the `#foo` element, because it doesn't exist yet.

But if you have

```
<div id="foo">..</div>
<script>/* your code here */</script>
```

...the element exists and your code can find it.

You have three choices:

1. Use event delegation, where you hook the event on `document` but only respond to it if the event travelled through a `#foo` element during the bubbling phase. Example:

   ```
   $(document).on("click", "#foo", function() {
       // Do something
   });
   ```

   This works well unless something else will handle the event on a descendant element of `document` and prevent it bubbling.
2. Put the script *below* the elements it refers to in the HTML. This is [vastly preferred](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom). Any elements defined in the markup *above* the `script` tags will exist as of when your script runs. So the usual advice is put the `script` just before the closing `</body>` tag.
3. If you don't control where the `script` element goes, use jQuery's [`ready` function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       // Your code here
   });
   ```

   or the shortcut:

   ```
   $(function() {
       // Your code here
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute your script when the dom is ready. If you put the code into head it will get executed before the browser has loaded the dom inside body, therefore jquery can not find foo. If the code is in body after the element with id "foo" then it will have created the element before the javascript code gets executed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').on('click', '#foo', function(event) {
        alert('Hello World');
    });

});
```

If you wrap an on ready around your code it will again work. You could also use jQuery on, and tell jquery to listen on the body, this has the advantage that it will still work even if the element foo is loaded by ajax and inserted into the dom after ready got executed.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6uLHL/

Answer (score 0):

The comments and answers that tell you to wrap the code in `$(document).ready()` are correct but fail to mention why this happens.

This behavior occurs because when you try to excecute the script the DOM has not been created in its enterity and therefore the element you are looking for does not exist. When using `$(document).ready()` you make sure that the scripts run after the DOM is ready

Comment: can also be run right after the referenced  elements exist, before the full DOM is loaded